# Is it useful to put AudioRecord.getState() in a loop?

Tags: java, android

I'm working with some code that calls the [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) constructor:

```
AudioRecord listener = new AudioRecord(list of parameters);
do {} while (listener.getState() != AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED);
```

This code would seem to make sense if AudioRecord goes off in another thread and takes time to initialize. I'm not sure of this is the case though, and if it isn't it would seem a lot better to have the code just check and return an exception, lest an infinite loop is started at some point when initialization does actually fail (although I could just limit the number of checks to something finite).

Should I leave the code as it is or replace the second line with something like the following?

```
if(listener.getState() != AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
    throw new Exception("AudioRecord failed to initialize");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be very clear when you look at the source code:

```
public AudioRecord(int audioSource, int sampleRateInHz, int channelConfig, int audioFormat, 
            int bufferSizeInBytes)
    throws IllegalArgumentException {   
        mState = STATE_UNINITIALIZED;
        mRecordingState = RECORDSTATE_STOPPED;

        ... //parameter checks

        // native initialization
        //update native initialization when information about hardware init failure
        //due to capture device already open is available.
        int initResult = native_setup( new WeakReference<AudioRecord>(this), 
                mRecordSource, mSampleRate, mChannels, mAudioFormat, mNativeBufferSizeInBytes);
        if (initResult != SUCCESS) {
            loge("Error code "+initResult+" when initializing native AudioRecord object.");
            return; // with mState == STATE_UNINITIALIZED
        }

        mState = STATE_INITIALIZED;
    }
```

So you don't have to wait for its state transition. You only need to check the state after you call the constructor once. If there is anything wrong in the native_setup, the state will be STATE_UNINITIALIZED.

Answer (score 1):

I would say throw an exception. I have an app that uses AudioRecord with > 1000000 downloads and it doesn't have to wait for the AudioRecord state. ( and you would at least need a Thread.sleep() in your while loop to ensure that you don't consume 100% cpu while waiting for AudioRecord if you did need to do that.)